# like box isn't working

Tags: facebook-likebox

The like box didn't appear like the one in the preview mode in the facebook developer page. Is anybody experiencing the same thing?
Can anybody help me?

Differences:

1. The colors in the preview mode was the standard FB colors, whereas in my blog some were black.
2. The background of the box in the preview mode was white, whereas in my blog was black.

This the IFRAME that i got from FB:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FIndonesia-Travel-Guidebook%2F193922257303230&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=427" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dimas  The iframe version is transparent.  you can fix this by adding style

```
background-color: #ffffff;
```

Example of your iframe usage here:

http://shawnsspace.com/atests.php

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FIndonesia-Travel-Guidebook%2F193922257303230&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=427" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:427px; background-color: white;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```